# How can I convert time into decimal in excel?

Tags: excel

I was using a formula for converting hours greater than 24 hours but that formula gives an error when it comes to thousands of hours.

I want to convert 283398:02:08 into decimal, but every time I try it gives an error.

Comment: Excel specifications:  `Largest amount of time that can be entered:
9999:59:59`  What are you using for a formula, and what do you expect for output.

Comment: i was using this =IF(K6>TIME(24,0,0),TEXT(K6,"[h]:mm:ss")*24,K6) , but its not working is there any other way ? I just want this total time in decimal

Comment: Decimal hours?  Decimal Days?  Decimal Minutes?

Comment: for decimal hours please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel, the largest amount of time that can be entered manually is 9999:59:59.

If you are entering time manually and it is greater than that, it will be converted to a text string.

To convert the text string to decimal hours, you need to use text manipulation functions to split the string (by the colon) and multiply the hours*1, minutes*1/60, seconds *1/60/60

So, if you have Excel 2013+ with the `FILTERXML` function, you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),{1;0.0166666667;0.00027777778})
```

If the time is a number, and not a string, then just:

```
=A1*24
```

and format as a decimal number

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, I worked, result is satisfying, Thanks again

Comment: @Sidra.S Note my addendum for handling "real times" (eg if the time is an Excel time, and not a string.

Comment: Noted, Thanks For Help.